# What does the optional UK residence permit for EU/EFTA nationals look like?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, immigration, resident-permit, eu-citizens

A friend of mine, a Swedish national, is moving to London, and has decided to apply for an optional residence permit, info about which is found here https://www.gov.uk/eea-registration-certificate

My question is: what form does it actually take? Is it a visa-type sticker in the passport, an A4 paper sheet, or something else?

If it's a sticker, how is it issued if you apply for it on the basis of an ID Card, rather than a passport?

Comment: Actually, I would expect a credit-card sized plastic card much like residence cards and common format residence permits, possibly with a different colour scheme (I held such a card in other countries) but my expectation was wrong (see answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's neither a plastic card, nor a sticker. It's a piece of paper (blue actually) which has three pages with usual info; the third page has the name, picture and the usual details.

See

https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/441957/employers_guide_to_acceptable_right_to_work_documents_v5.pdf

(page 15)

Comment: Actually, this document confirms that it can be sticker but also explains what the alternative is (+1).

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Guess it means that if you apply for it with a passport, the sticker's pasted into it, while with an ID Card you get the blue paper with the sticker pasted onto it. I think it could be a suitable solution even after Brexit (but with the certificate obviously becoming mandatory)

Comment: I actually sent passport with the application and received the blue paper, i.e. no sticker. But i guess it doesnt really matter. If the person is moving the UK, they'll only get a certificate (the permanent residence is obtained after 5 years in the UK)

Answer (score 1):

[PRADO indicates it is a sticker](http://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/GBR-HO-02001/index.html) (which is kind of odd, considering the fact that holding a passport is by no means necessary for most EU citizens living in the UK). The website provides extensive details about its appearance and security features, along with a [list of related documents](http://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/prado-documents/gbr/h/index.html) (cards for family members, permanent residence cards, accession worker card).

Comment: Wow, question is then how it's issued if applied for on the basis of an ID card